# Bitwise operations in Java: Test if in "1010101111011" a bit is set?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

Let's say, I have some user input (as a String) like "11010011011".

Now I want to check if a bit at a bit at a particular position is set (each digit should act as a flag).

Note: I am receiving the user's input as a String.

How can I do that?

Comment: Cant u use `charAt(position)` method ? And compare the value is 0/1?

Comment: Why do you have to use bitwise operations to do this?!?!?!

Comment: I have no idea what would be the best way to do that. Maybe I would not need bitwise operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could work with the string as is - say you want to check the first bit on the left:

```
if (input.charAt(0) == '1') { //
```

Alternatively if you want to work with a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) you can initialise it in a loop:

```
String input = "11010011011";
BitSet bs = new BitSet(input.length());
int i = 0;
for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '1') bs.set(i);
    i++;
}
```

Then to check if the i-th bit is set:

```
boolean isSet = bs.get(i);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use bitwise operations, then first convert the string to integer and test with bitmasks:

```
int val = Integer.parseInt("11010011011", 2);
System.out.println(val & (1<<0)); //First bit
System.out.println(val & (1<<1)); //Second bit
System.out.println(val & (1<<2)); //Third bit
.....
```